# clarification about real and imaginary parts in complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

I am unsure if I got the correct real and imaginary parts.

$e^{3} * e^{-j\frac{\pi}{4}} = e^{3} (\cos(\frac{\pi}{4}) -j\sin(\frac{\pi}{4}))$.

Is the real part then: $e^{3}\cos(\frac{\pi}{4}) = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}e^{3} $

Then the imaginary part is: $\sin(\frac{\pi}{4}) = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$

Comment: The imaginary part is $-e^3\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}$. Do you see why?

Comment: what is $j$ ? in math context should be primitive root of $j^3=1$, but you seem to use electricity notation for $i$.

Comment: $j$ could also be one of the quaternionic imaginaries. They are usually called $i,j,k$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
e^3\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-j\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \right)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} e^3 -j \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}e^3
$$

so the real part is $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} e^3 $ as you found , but the imaginary part is $-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} e^3 $

Answer (score 0):

$${ e }^{ 3 }\cdot { e }^{ -i\frac { \pi  }{ 4 }  }={ e }^{ 3 }\left( \cos { \left( -\frac { \pi  }{ 4 }  \right) +i\sin { \left( -\frac { \pi  }{ 4 }  \right)  }  }  \right) ={ e }^{ 3 }\cos { \left( \frac { \pi  }{ 4 }  \right)  } +i{ e }^{ 3 }\sin { \left( -\frac { \pi  }{ 4 }  \right)  } \\ Re\left( { e }^{ 3 }\cdot { e }^{ -i\frac { \pi  }{ 4 }  } \right) ={ e }^{ 3 }\cos { \left( \frac { \pi  }{ 4 }  \right)  } =\frac { { e }^{ 3 } }{ \sqrt { 2 }  } \\ Im\left( { e }^{ 3 }\cdot { e }^{ -i\frac { \pi  }{ 4 }  } \right) ={ e }^{ 3 }\sin { \left( -\frac { \pi  }{ 4 }  \right)  } =-\frac { { e }^{ 3 } }{ \sqrt { 2 }  } $$

Answer (score 0):

$$
e^{3}e^{-j\frac{\pi}{4}}=e^{3}(\cos(-\pi/4)+j\sin(-\pi/4))=e^{3}\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-je^{3}\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}.
$$
Real part: $e^{3}\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$

Imaginary part: $-e^{3}\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ (you forgot the minus sign and the $e^{3}$ factor).